# How to change the text value of an input inside an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript function that goes and gets me a form from another page on the same site. It returns an HTML element (the form) and everything in it. Inside that form, there is an input with no value.

Let's say we have this:

```
var form = $(data).filter("form")[0];
```

Now form has an html element that is the form. The form itself has an input element inside it.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
$(form.input).text("something new");
```

and have that change the value of the input inside the form which is *not* on the page but inside a variable.

Just want to clarify again that the form (in the variable form) is not on the page, it is saved inside a variable.

Comment: All the methods for changing the DOM in jQuery work the same whether the object is actually in the DOM or in memory. Seems like if you'd tried anything you would have figured that out.

Comment: Where is the variable stored?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(form).find("input").val("something new");
```

- [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the child `input` tag (or [`.children("input")`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) if you know `input` is a direct child of the form).
- [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the input's value.  (Note that `.text` sets the inner text of an HTML tag, which of course you don't want in this case.)

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/aVQ3G/5/)

Comment: When I console.log the form again after the statement for example, I still see no value for the input in the form. The value of input inside the variable itself hasn't changed.

Comment: @user220755 can you provide a demo showing what you mean?  It's working as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/aVQ3G/1/

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle and I do not see any results, am I missing something?

Comment: @user220755 try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aVQ3G/5/  I was seeing some weird results in the console window -- not sure what's up, but it does seem the value is being set.

Answer (score 0):

To set all inputs in your form:

```
$(form).find('input').each(function(index,inputObj){
  $(this).val('someting');
});
```

Basically, you need to know what input you are looking for. You will need to know some way of identifying it i.e. either id, name, css class name etc. Here is a reference to jquery selectors you can use:
[Jquery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
e.g. if need to set value of an input with name "id", I will do this

```
$(form).('input[name="id"]').val("id is set");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: $(form).('input[name="id"]').val("id is set"); this is returning unexpected token (

Comment: make sure you have a input with name attribute id e.g. <input type="text" name="id" >.
Can you post markup?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to find to do this is to:

```
$(form).find("input")[1].setAttribute("value", "something")
```

Comment: Why mix jQuery and the usual JavaScript?

Comment: To be honest, I did not intend to, it is just that all the other solutions mentioned here (including val for example) did not work (I commented on each one of why it did not work)

Comment: `.val()` should work as usual. The problem is that your question has been rather vague.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
 $(form).find("input").each(function(){
     val("something new");
  });
```

Comment: .find will return a collection of all inputs no?